# Settings screen for app is throwing an exception

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I was trying to use the settings flyout in phone 8.1 runtime to produce a settings screen for an app. However the compiler is throwing an error and I dont no why. This would have worked fine in phone 8.0 but not 8.1 runtime it seems.

```
<SettingsFlyout
x:Class="popcornpk.Settings"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:popcornpk"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
IconSource="Assets/SmallLogo.png"
Title="CustomSetting"   >

<!-- This StackPanel acts as a root panel for vertical layout of the content sections -->
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

    <!-- Toggle switch -->
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBlock Text="Toggle Switch" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,25" Text="Use toggle switches to let users set Boolean values." Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <ToggleSwitch Margin="-6,0,0,0" Header = "Download updates automatically" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
        <ToggleSwitch Margin="-6,0,0,0" Header = "Install updates automatically" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- Button -->
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBlock Text="Push button" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Button label" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <Button Margin="-3,0,0,0" Content="Clear"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,25" Text="With a push button, users initiate an immediate action." Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- ComboBox -->
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBlock Text="ComboBox" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,25" Text="Use the ComboBox to allow users to select one item from a set of text-only items." Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <ComboBox Header="State:" Margin="0,7,0,0" SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Washington"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Oregon"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="California"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- HyperlinkButton -->
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBlock Text="Hyperlink" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,25" Text="Use a hyperlink when the associated action will take the user out of this flyout." Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <HyperlinkButton Padding="-5,0,0,0" Content="View privacy statement" Tag="http://privacy.microsoft.com" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- TextBox -->
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBlock Text="TextBox" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,25" Text="Use a TextBox to allow users to enter text." Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,7,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150"/>
            <Button Margin="20,0,0,0" Content="Add"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <!-- RadioButton -->
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Radio button group" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,25" Text="Lets users choose one item from a small set of mutually exclusive, related options." Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Video quality" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <RadioButton Margin="0,7,0,0" Content="High"/>
        <RadioButton Margin="0,17,0,0" Content="Medium"/>
        <RadioButton Margin="0,17,0,0" Content="Low"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0263  Partial declarations of 'Settings' must not specify different base classes  popcornpk   C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\81StoreLiveAppsPhoneOnlyLIVE\popcornpk\popcornpkhub\popcornpk\popcornpk\obj\Debug\Settings.g.i.cs   15

My base class is just the same as other pages 
**Note 2**

> public partial class Settings : Page

I changed above to settings and it compiled but the flyount did not work or popup so it didnt any idea as to why it didnt.

**Note 2** 
To Avoid confusion I dont want a base page of page I wanted to be able to use the settingsflyout that was part of 8.0 apparently microsoft have dicthced this though for 8.1 UAP

Comment: Try to start your XAML like this: `<Page ...>` not `<SettingsFlyout ..>`.

Comment: this is for a settings flyout romaz please see the documenttation on msdn which does not start with page as per msdn

Comment: If you want to have a base class `Page` in the code behind, the xaml part must have the same base class - as [Will has explained in his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32271815/2681948).

Comment: I dont want to have a base class of page read the question properly its asettings flyout i am trying to acheive not a page in 8.1 runtime theirfore i need to no what goes their but i found that i need settings their but its still not showing the settings flyout !

Comment: Then how this 'flyout' is implemented? (page, popup, other?) How you invoke it? (navigate, show, other?) Your question seems to lack most relevant information.

Comment: Its invoked by settings my question does not plz look here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh872190.aspx

Comment: Heh, I wasn't aware of *SettingsFlyout* - then why don't you try to make it your base class in the code? `public partial class Settings : SettingsFlyout`

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells you everything you need to know.

Look at your xaml.  Here's the top two lines of your file:

```
<SettingsFlyout
    x:Class="popcornpk.Settings"
```

This says that you're declaring a new class called `popcornpk.Settings` (btw, namespaces should be PascalCased) that extends the base class `SettingsFlyout`.

When you add a new xaml file to your application, it actually creates three files--the .xaml file, a .xaml.cs file that you edit, and a mysterious ephemeral .g.i.cs file that holds designer-generated code (e.g., the implementation of `InitializeComponent()`).

The .xaml.cs and .g.i.cs files are *partial class files*, and are combined by the compiler.  Note what the exception message says--

> Partial declarations of 'Settings' **must not specify different base classes**

What are these different base classes?

Well, from the xaml, we can see the first one--**SettingsFlyout**.

From your snippet,

> public partial class Settings : Page

We see the other base class--**Page**.

Not sure how you screwed that up, but the simple fix is to remove the base class declaration from your .xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class Settings
{
    // snip
```

Comment: if you look at my notes I have already done this and adjusted but still settings is not showing it must be removed from 8.1 runtime

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what [Will has said about *partial* classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32271815/2681948), which will surely solve the error, you probably won't be able to use [SettingsFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.settingsflyout.aspx) on Phone - following the remarks:

> Caution  SettingsFlyout is supported only for use with the SettingsPane in Windows 8. While the SettingsFlyout type is visible in Windows Phone projects, SettingsPane is not present on Windows Phone, so use of SettingsFlyout is not supported.